# Understanding a scalar function involving a matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=\{a_{ij}\}$ be a strictly substochastic matrix, let $x$ be a scalar in $[0,1]$, and let $$\Lambda(x) \equiv \{\lambda_{ij}(x)\} \equiv(I-xA^{T})^{-1}.$$ Consider the function $$f(x) = \left[x+(1-x)\lambda_{kk}(x)\right]\frac{1}{x}\left[1-\left(1-x\right)\sum_{i}\lambda_{ik}(x)\right].$$ Simulations reveal that $f(x) \leq 1$ for $x\in[0,1]$. I would like to prove this.

It is easy to see that $f(1) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 1$. One could differentiate and show that $f(x)$ is convex, but this seems quite involved. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\rho(A)<1$ and $x\leq 1$ then $I-xA$ is an M-matrix, and so all the entries of $\Lambda(x)$ are positive. This implies that
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) & =\left[x+\left(1-x\right)\lambda_{kk}(x)\right]\frac{1}{x}\left[1-\left(1-x\right)\sum_{i}\lambda_{ik}(x)\right]\\
 & =\left[x+\left(1-x\right)\left(1+\lambda_{kk}(x)-1\right)\right]\frac{1}{x}\left[1-\left(1-x\right)\left[1+\sum_{i}\lambda_{ik}(x)-1\right]\right]\\
 & =\left[1+\left(1-x\right)\left(\lambda_{kk}(x)-1\right)\right]\left[1-\left(1-x\right)\left(\frac{\sum_{i}\lambda_{ik}(x)-1}{x}\right)\right]\\
 & \leq\left[1+\left(1-x\right)\left(\lambda_{kk}(x)-1\right)\right]\left[1-\left(1-x\right)\left(\sum_{i}\lambda_{ik}(x)-1\right)\right]\\
 & \leq\left[1+\left(1-x\right)\left(\lambda_{kk}(x)-1\right)\right]\left[1-\left(1-x\right)\left(\lambda_{kk}(x)-1\right)\right]\\
 & =1-\left(1-x\right)^{2}\left(\lambda_{kk}(x)-1\right)^{2}\leq1
\end{align*}$$